# Will I have to file Massachusetts tax forms if I have almost no income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

I am moving out of Massachusetts in October, but it unclear to me whether I will need to fill out a Massachusetts tax form. I expect to have less than $10 in income in 2018, which is interest on a bank account in Massachusetts. I would really rather not fill out 12 pages of tax forms because of $10 in interest income.

Unfortunately the [tax form and "instructions" page the Mass DOR has published](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/dor-personal-income-tax-forms-and-instructions#2018-draft-massachusetts-personal-income-tax-forms-and-instructions-) actually has no instructions that I can find, so I cannot figure out the rules, because there are no instructions.

Comment: One reason a person might want to file even if it is not required is because it starts the clock on the [statute of limitations](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/view-statutes-of-limitations-for-tax-related-matters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the MA Dept. of Revenue hasn't yet published the instructions for the 2018 tax year.  That said, [the instructions for the 2017 part-year resident form](https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2018/05/02/dor-2017-inc-form-1-nrpy-inst.pdf) state that:

> **You must file a Massachusetts Nonresident/Part-Year Resident Income Tax Return, Massachusetts Form 1-NR/PY, if** you were not a resident of Massachusetts and you received Massachusetts source income in excess of your personal exemption multiplied by the ratio of your Massachusetts income to your total income, or **you were not a resident of Massachusetts for the full year and your gross income was more than $8,000 — whether received from sources inside or outside of Massachusetts.**

(Bolding mine.)

If this rule continues to hold for the 2018 tax year, and you only have $10 of income total (even from sources outside of MA), then you won't need to file.